# Handle sessions using Express-Sessions

Tags: angularjs, node.js, session, express, express-session

Im new working with nodeJS. I have a webpage (with AngularJS) in a AWS ec2-server that gets information from a nodeJS(Express) server.  Im trying to keep logged my users once they log in, even if they refresh. I have read that I can do that using express-sessions. This is my code in the client side:

```
$http({
method: 'GET',
url: 'http://ec2-bla-bla-bla.compute.amazonaws.com:8080/verifySession'
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
   console.log(response);
}, function errorCallback(response) {

});

//And here i have the http post method that call login webservice
```

This is my server code:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var path =  require("path");
var session = require('express-session');
var app = express();
var loginManual = require('./model/ws_package/loginManual.js');

var sess;

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With,    Content-Type, Accept");
next();
});
app.use(session({secret: 'ssshhhhh'}));
app.use( bodyParser.json() );       // to support JSON-encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({     // to support URL-encoded bodies
extended: true
})); 

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname + '/view'))); 

app.get('/verify',function(req,res){

   sess=req.session;
   if(sess.email){
    res.send({state:1,email: sess.email});
   }
   else{
    res.send({state:-1,email: "NE"});
   }
});



app.post("/login",function(req, res)
{
var userEmail; //here is myuseremail
//I have some login code here and if it is successful:              
sess = req.session;
sess.email=userEmail;
res.send(response);
}               
);
```

It is not working, but when I tested /login and /verify webservices, directly in my browser, writing the url, it works. Another thing I discovered is that everytime I make a new $http method from angular, my session id changes, so I dont know if that could mean something that affects me. How can I solve this? Sorry for my english, i am Costa Rican! Thanks!

Comment: Can you please show the code where you have assigned value to `req.session`.

Comment: Here it is https://jsfiddle.net/f0gvevfv/2/